# Can I develop android application that works with Samsung S3 and other android at the same time

Tags: android, mobile

I would like to know more about android applications development, I want to start coding an application using

[This SDK](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) and I don't know whether it will be compatibale with Samsung galaxy 3 and/or other mobile devices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's why Android is called "platform". Many devices, the same OS. In general you **should** be writting one single app that works perfectly on any android device (more/less :)

Rule of thumb - write for Android. Not for Samsung S3 (unless you absolutely know you need to write just for samsung s3 and you know what you doing)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I read that I should take into consideration the different screen size of the devices and that is why I should start with a specific size and then scale it up or down.. but is the size the only concern I should worry about when developing for almost all android ? I asked about specifically Samsung galaxy because I bought one recently, so I would be able to perfrm some testing with it!

Comment: @user573014 Do the training you linked in your question. It has all sorts of nice tips, the code examples are really good (a lot here are pretty bad compared to that) and it should mention all the important things to consider. I learned a lot from there.

Comment: I am glad that you found it useful, I will start with their tutorials